# Как разместить изображение в кнопку win forms

Tags: c#, winforms

Столкнулся с проблемой при написании игры. Логику готова, то есть кнопка спавнится в рандомных 6 точках.(Фото ниже) Необходимо сделать так, чтобы там было изображение, а не вид кнопки с надписью "target". Кнопка прописана через таймер, вот код:

```
        {
            isHit = false;
            btn_click.Enabled = true;
            btn_click.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Transparent;

            locationNum = rnd.Next(1, 7);


            switch (locationNum)
            {
                case 1:
                    btn_click.Left = 186;
                    btn_click.Top = 297;
                    break;

                case 2:
                    btn_click.Left = 43;
                    btn_click.Top = 327;
                    break;

                case 3:
                    btn_click.Left = 325;
                    btn_click.Top = 333;
                    break;

                case 4:
                    btn_click.Left = 60;
                    btn_click.Top = 402;
                    break;

                case 5:
                    btn_click.Left = 309;
                    btn_click.Top = 406;
                    break;

                case 6:
                    btn_click.Left = 187;
                    btn_click.Top = 450;
                    break;

                default:
                    break;
            }
        }
```

[image: Вот].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public button addButton(string nameBtn, Image img)
        {
            button btn = new button();
            btn.Name = nameBtn;
            btn.BackgroundImageLayout = ImageLayout.Center; //Положение картинки на кнопке.
            btn.BackgroundImage = img; 
            btn.Height = 50;
            btn.Width = 50;
            btn.FlatStyle = FlatStyle.Flat;    //Убираем фон
            btn.FlatAppearance.BorderSize = 0; //Убираем края(обводку)
            //Так же можно добавить позиционирование(если нид) 
            btn.Location = new Point(X, Y);
            return btn;
        }
```

применение:

```
panel1.Controls.Add(addButton("btn1", Resources.NameImage));
```

Или делаем через свойства объекта:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Выбираем нужную картинку:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

FlatStyle:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

FlatAppearance:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И ещё одно, по своей природе winforms не поддерживает прозрачность формы и элементов, но это лечится(костылем). ИЛИ! можно сделать точно также только с `PictureBox`. С ней вроде полегче придумать прозрачность.

Оставлю все равно здесь:

[О PictureBox и Button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10763640/c-sharp-windows-form-application-transparent-button)

[Возможное решение проблемы прозрачности](https://christian-helle.blogspot.com/2008/01/transparent-controls-in-netcf.html)

Comment: Как-то можно убрать задний фон при наведении курсора на кнопку?

Comment: @Parcurcik, конечно, но это уже совсем другой вопрос ): советую задать новый, с новыми вводными.

Comment: @Parcurcik, Я слегка дополнил ответ, ибо такое поведение наблюдаю первый раз, мне оно было не известно(возможно из-за ненадобности) но все же...

Comment: Спасибо, однако дело в том, что фон у меня лежит в Form1, а не в picturebox

Comment: @Parcurcik, тогда же все проще вроде как